# Is literature as in 'the literature' singular or plural

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

When referring to literature in the sense of academic literature or philosophical literature I have sometimes heard people use the noun as if it were similar to the word 'people.' For example: 'The literature have confirmed this hypothesis.' I have also heard people use the noun as if it were singular (e.g. 'The literature has confirmed this hypothesis.'

Is there one usage that is more acceptable/correct in formal writing?

Comment: *The literature has* is correct; *the literature have* is not correct, IMO. Ngram says [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+literature+has%2C+the+literature+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20literature%20has%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20literature%20have%3B%2Cc0), FWIW.

Comment: See some of the similar questions of the past on this site. Many words have this double-existence. E.g., http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/is-audience-singular-or-plural?rq=1 http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/157166/is-statistics-singular-or-plural?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

*Literature* is typically used to describe a collective *body of writings*; as such, it takes a singular verb despite the fact it refers to many works. The word is almost always preceded by an adjective or attributive noun to identify a specific body of works:

**English literature**

**scientific literature**

**product literature** (archaic)

Literature also connotes writings of higher quality within the category and can be used in a plural form, *literatures*, but is rarely called for.

**Of all the Asian literatures, Asian poetry attracts me most.**

Comment: Fine, but how does that answer the question at hand?

Comment: "... it takes a singular noun despite the fact it refers to many works." (Of course, I meant "verb."